# Population genetics: analysis of allele frequency distribution along environmental gradients

Tags: r, predictive-models, simulation, genetics, environmental-data

Is there a software or a R package that does a simulation of spatial distribution of alleles? I'm interested in how a distribution of alleles of functional loci is shaped by a pattern of environmental variables, such as temperatures and water quality.

I have data on geographical patterns of environmental variables, population connectivity (Fst)(microsatellite data), geographic distances, population size and allele frequency of functional loci at 17 sites.

I want to know allele frequency of the functional loci at other sites in a map for which we don't have allele frequency data.

Maybe using existing allele frequency data (from functional loci) and other information mentioned above, allele frequency at other sites could be predicted with an assumption that loci are under selection of targeted environmental variables?

Thanks!